# mat stepper step completed & valid but not done

Tags: angular, mat-stepper

I am using mat-stepper with formGroup on each step. I fill form on then step and then click to the next and even if  form is valid previous doesn`t become done (it satays edit and with mat-step-icon-selected)

As i understood it is default behavior: step is completed and valid -> done. Am I right?

What can be wrong in my case?

Comment: so there mode in steeper call linear mode for Whether the validity of previous steps should be checked or not.
https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api#MatHorizontalStepper

Comment: even in Linear mode step doesn`t become done and icon doesn`t get mat-step-icon-done (it validates, I can`t move to the next step before current is invalid, but that`s all

Answer (score 3):

I`ve found the solution:

```
import {STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS} from '@angular/cdk/stepper';

providers: [{
    provide: STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue: {displayDefaultIndicatorType: false}
}]
```

and without Linear mode step gets done state